# Getting underlying type of a proxy object

Tags: c#, reflection, proxy, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm using Castle DynamicProxy and my ViewModels are a proxy, something like this:

```
namespace MyApplication.ViewModels
{
   public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel, IMyViewModel
   {
   }
}
```

a proxy of my viewmodel looks like this though:

{Name = "IRootViewModelProxyffecb133f590422098ca7c0ac13b8f98" FullName = "IRootViewModelProxyffecb133f590422098ca7c0ac13b8f98"}

I want to get the actual type or namespace of the actual type that is being proxied. Is there any way to do this? I want something that returns MyApplication.ViewModels.MyViewModel type. If I'm using concreate class as proxies, BaseType returns the actual class that is being proxied, but when using the interface, BaseType would return System.Object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems you can do the following to get the actual type:

```
(proxy As IProxyTargetAccessor).DynProxyGetTarget().GetType()
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. Notice though, that DynProxyGetTarget() can return null, if proxy has no target.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @hadi-eskandari Scorpions :)

Comment: @Mertez haha you're most welcome Morry :)

Answer (score 15):

If you are proxying a class and not an interface, you can get the underlying type like this:

```
var unproxiedType = ProxyUtil.GetUnproxiedType(proxy);
```

If you don't have access to ProxyUtil this will also work:

```
private static Type GetUnproxiedType(object source)
{
   var proxy = (source as IProxyTargetAccessor);

   if (proxy == null)
     return source.GetType();

   return proxy.GetType().BaseType;            
}
```

Comment: Yeah, however this class is part of Windsor not DynamicProxy, so it's not always available

Comment: Krzysztof suggested that first solution will not work for users who do not use Castle Windsor, so I modified the answer.

Comment: BTW I think `ProxyUtil` might be a useful thing in DP itself so I'll port it from Windsor to DynamicProxy for the next version.