# What is Alternative for GetType().Name : for delete proxy from end of Name

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I have a project by NHibernate implementation and using Lazy Loading. Of course have been implemented in two project : one project for NHibernate implementation and second project for Domain implementation. I have a entity in Domain project by this name : *Person*

```
Public Person : EntityBase
{

}
```

I loaded a entity by this code:

```
TEntity entity = SessionInstance.Load<TEntity>(110);
```

In my Domain Project use of this entity by this code:

```
string strName = entity.GetType().Name;
if(strName == "Person")
{
    //My Code
}
```

Problem is here. *strName* at some stage is **"Person"** and it is correct But sometimes *strName* is **"PersonProxy"**

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this to avoid hard coding the Person string? If so, I would do the following:

```
typeof(Person).Name
```

If it needs to be dynamic, perhaps this will work

```
    public String GetDomainName(Type type)
    {
        var isNotFromDomain = type.Namespace != typeof(Person).Namespace;
        if (isNotFromDomain)
            return GetDomainName(type.BaseType);
        return type.Name;
    }
```

And finally, based on your updated code I suggest you consider the following. I like to avoid hard coded strings.

```
if (entity is Person)
{
    //My Code
}
```

Comment: @lain I edit my question. My method is for load a Entity instead of a Person. Thank you for your notice!

Comment: @Ehsan: The second method should work then. I have assumed the proxy namespace is not the same as the domain namespace. I am not that familiar with the proxies.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `is` operator.

But be careful: Usually it works with proxies, but it won't work with proxies of entities that are mapped with inheritance. The reason for that is that the proxy type extends only the base class of an entity mapped by inheritance. But there are workarounds for that problem, some are explained here: [How do I get the entity type on an object that may be a NHibernate proxy object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755841/how-do-i-get-the-entity-type-on-an-object-that-may-be-a-nhibernate-proxy-object)